# const char **p comparison between pointer and integer if (**p == NULL)

Tags: c, pointers, null, char

I am defining a function where one of the argument is `const char **p`. I understand that it means 'declare p as pointer to pointer to const char'. Now I want to check if the const char is NULL character and thus check `(**p == NULL)` but it gives warning that `warning: comparison between pointer and integer`. Here is the code example

```
   bool func(const char **p)
     {   if (**p == NULL)
             return false;}
```

I am not sure why it's complaining so. Isn't **p supposed to dereference the character value pointer *p points to? Or am I making confusion between `NULL` and `'\0'`?

Comment: Yes, you are confusing `NULL` and `'\0'`. `NULL` makes no sense in this context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NULL is a macro defining a *null-pointer constant*, not the ASCII character NUL.  If you want to test for a character NUL, then:

```
if( **p == '\0' )
```

or more simply:

```
if( **p == 0 )
```

Comment: `NULL` is a null pointer *constant*, which is not necessarily a pointer. It can be defined as a pointer though.

Comment: @Ant : In general yes, but in this specific question NULL is a pointer - hence the error, so the answer remains valid.

Comment: Yes, but the language itself makes a very clear distinction between *null pointer constant* and *null pointer*. These are two rather different concepts. For which reason referring to `NULL` as a *null pointer* sounds rather misleading.

Comment: @Ant : I think I misunderstood your original point (I thout you were referring to the difference between `0` and `((void*)0)`. I have modified the text; feel free to make changes if you feel it improves it.  But let's be clear here the definition and meaning of NULL are largely irrelevant in this case since the error was the misconception that NULL defines the NUL character.  Language-lawyer "noise" about NULL is a side issue.